# On premise and push notifications for progressive web applications (PWA)

Tags: push-notification, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Assuming that you are creating an enterprise web application, that runs in a corporate (on-premise) environment that does not have a connection to the internet.

Is it possible to use progressive web apps push notifications in this case? Maybe some server-side solution that can push notification to the clients?

I mean, now if you try to do that, you'll get endpoint like "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/bla-bla-bla" (for Chrome for example, for Firefox it'll be different). What if the Google/Mozilla/whatever services are NOT accessible to the users (you can imagine,  they run in an isolated corporate LAN)?

Answer (score -2):

There's nothing voodoo about the push api, it's just http requests in a pretty wrapper. The problem you will have is each user agent has a built in preset push server which cannot be changed, so you would be in for some fairly serious work if you wanted to come up with your own push server and client solution.

It's not really necessary for an intranet solution though. The push api is just a protocol for data transfer, the notifications api is entirely separate. You could implement a central websocket server and create browser notifications in response to websocket messages easily enough with a few lines of javascript, and the end result would be basically the same.

Comment: Will it work in service worker (when user did not even open my website?)

Comment: No, service workers can not have persistent connections. Your best bet is probably to develop internal desktop apps or browser extensions that maintain persistent connections.

Comment: As of my understanding, a standard service worker push notifications will work even in case when the user did not even open the website that installed the service worker, correct? https://w3c.github.io/push-api/#introduction ... I was wondering, if this feature can be used for an isolated LAN scenario.

Comment: The push api can invoke a service worker to display a notification, but this wouldn't really be feasible unless you have total control of the LAN and are willing to proxy all the browser push servers in your dns and set up your own push api compliant server. Service workers are intended to have a limited lifespan, once they have performed their task they exit, you can't keep one alive to poll a server or anything. You might be able to do something using the background sync api and trick a service worker into regular syncs. I think there are better ways of doing what you are trying to do